# Is the iframe sandbox attribute with every permission given equivalent to not using sandbox?

Tags: html, iframe, sandbox

If I want only to disallow popups, do I need to add `sandbox` and all possible values but `allow-popups`?

So basically, is the sandbox attribute just the sum of its togglable values, or is there some additional measures taken that cannot be toggled at all?